# Why does nspredicate crash?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data

I wanted to check if a field contains data or not.  Here's my code:

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                            @"( SeriesStudyID ==  %@ )" ,"" ]];
```

But it crashes.  Why?

Comment: You are passing a C-string where an Objective-C object is expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@iAnand's answer is wrong.  Using `%@` in a predicate format string is perfectly acceptable.

The problem is that `%@` means to substitute in an object, but you're substituting in `""`, which is *not* an object, but a `char*`.  Thus, you need to simply add an `@` sign in front of the double quotes to turn it from a `char*` into an `NSString`.